# How consider NA using ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this file:

```
Animal Bull   Breed     
Billy   1     Angus
Freddy  1     Nelore
Jone    NA    Nelore
Peter   2     Charoles
```

And I have some wrong breeds, and I needed to correct.

I needed the file this way:

```
 Animal Bull   Breed     
 Billy   1     Angus
 Freddy  1     Angus
 Jone    NA    Nelore
 Peter   2     Charoles
```

And I used this code:

```
df$Breed <- with(df, ifelse(Bull=='1', 'ANGUS', Breed))
```

But I got this data file:

```
Animal Bull   Breed     
Billy   1     Angus
Freddy  1     Angus
Jone    NA    NA
Peter   2     Charoles
```

When the Bull is `NA` the Breed disappears too. What happen? 
OBS: The Bull name is character.

Comment: Try `df$Breed <- with(df, replace(Breed, Bull=='1', 'ANGUS'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use `is.na()`:

You could write a condition to consider missing values with `is.na()`. For example:

```
df$Breed <- with(df, ifelse(Bull=='1' & !is.na(Bull), 'Angus', Breed))


#>   Animal   Bull Breed   
#> 1 Billy       1 Angus   
#> 2 Freddie     1 Angus   
#> 3 Jone       NA Nelore  
#> 4 Peter       2 Charoles
```